# Where can I get a reliable and a updated Airport API or Airport Database, and I also want to know the charges for the API?

Tags: airport

Kindly guide me where can I get a reliable and updated airport Master API. The airport API should have all the information about all the airports in the world and I also want to know how much do they charge for the API.

Comment: what does `how would be the plans and pricing for the Airport master` mean?

Comment: I just want to know where can i get the airport API and how much does it costs.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question.  It's clear what the person is asking for, the fact that it's out of his price range doesn't mean the question can't help future visitors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because resource location is specifically off-topic defined in the help center.

Comment: @gerry do you think it would be better suited in [opendata.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ManuH I believe it would.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Location Identifiers** & Airline Designators data files available with **daily updates**
>
> The perfect solution to feeding your coding database. These files (more information in right hand column) are available as a 12 month subscription or a one-time web download. For the subscription, you will be granted access to the password protected extranet site upon purchase where you can retrieve the data files update daily.

http://www.iata.org/publications/Pages/coding.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the information RedGrittyBrick, but the price for the data is to high are there any other sites where i could get the data at a lower cost.Since we are a startup company we cant afford such high price.

Comment: @NivinAbraham If you can't afford IATA, check out [ourairports.org](http://ourairports.org). Also see http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/can-two-airports-have-a-different-icao-code-but-share-the-same-iata-code

Comment: Thanks a lot Danny Bekett, the URL you provided was very helpful.The data are  very accurate and the also it is up to date.

Answer (score 2):

[Navigraph](https://www.navigraph.com/FmsDataManager.aspx) and [Aerosoft](https://www.aerosoft.com/en/fsxp3d/flight-simulator-2004/tools-missions/1750/navdatapro-one-year-subscription-13-datasets) provide relatively cheap (~€25/yr) subscription to regular AIRAC updates for the simulation community. The databases include all the airport information that is required for FMS (navigation).

In both cases, the databases are plain-text files which are rather trivial to parse without any special API. For example:

```
A,YMML,MELBOURNE INTL,-37.673333,144.843333,434,10000,11000,11900,0
R,09,83,7500,148,0,0.000,0,-37.660756,144.822247,395,3.00,50,1,0
R,16,161,11998,197,1,109.700,160,-37.653192,144.834911,432,3.00,50,1,0
R,27,263,7500,148,1,109.300,263,-37.662261,144.848089,407,3.00,50,1,0
R,34,341,11998,197,0,0.000,0,-37.685789,144.840994,330,3.00,50,1,0

IMS,YMML ILS/CAT III,109.700,0,1,195,-37.656667,144.833611,434,YM,0,0,11.5,0.0
IMW,YMML ILS/CAT I,109.300,0,0,195,-37.660000,144.810000,434,YM,0,0,0.0,0.0
```

One can get a free sample of the whole database (at some point in the past) with a demo version of some software packages that use such database; for example, [this one](https://www.fs-flightcontrol.com/en/).