# Where can I find current downloadable tower, ground and approach frequencies for USA airports?

Tags: airport, usa, faa, frequency

I have searched the FAA site and cannot find a spreadsheet with current freqs for airports, only incomplete lists.  Online flight planning tools must get query-able current freqs on a monthly basis, but I sure couldn't find them.

I'm looking for what Airnav, the Chart Supp US, AOPA flight planner all provide if you search on a specific airport, but in a format I can query from a personal spreadsheet.

Comment: Searching for "Airport Database" gave [this result](https://ourairports.com/data/)...

Comment: Didn't think of searching on that phrase... Close, but no cigar.  I am wary of open source data, and I was bummed to find that a navaid local to me (PGY VORTAC) had not had its frequency updated on this site even though the data says it is current as of today.  That means they are not pulling from current info.  Any other good ideas?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8473/where-can-i-get-a-reliable-and-a-updated-airport-api-or-airport-database-and-i/); but it is more about NAVAID frequencies rather than voice frequencies.

Answer (score 3):

I have found something that will work. It is not pretty and I swear I can still smell the punch cards that produced the text files, but here it is:

https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/NASR_Subscription

It is free, it appears to be updated by the FAA, (I verified it has the current frequency for my local VOR that I know changed 2 months ago) and it is searchable.

Download the current zip file, use the .txt data layout files to determine where in the fixed length record of whatever file your desired data resides in is located.  I did a quick import into Excel and am able to strip the information that I need out based on position in the field.

Not the pretty spreadsheet I was hoping for, but ...

Thanks for the suggestions, everyone. If anyone knows any standard software for the NASR subscription (or what the !@*# NASR stands for), I'd be interested.

Comment: Once you get your spreadsheet cleaned up, will you publish it for all of us who are not so enterprising?

Comment: @PJNoes, I will try to do that, although since the FAA coughs out an update every 28 days, it would involve me simplifying the spreadsheet merge enough that anybody could do it.  I don't know VBA well enough to make that merge very user friendly, but we'll see.

Answer (score 1):

That information can be found on FAA.gov

You can use the [FAA's search tool](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/search/) rather than manually look in a copy of the chart supplement.

However, updated PDF copies of all of the chart supplements are hosted by the FAA [here](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/).

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but I'm looking for a complete list of all US airports and relevant frequencies that I can download and use offline via my own software. I am familiar with the digital chart supp US options, but pdf's are not searchable by SQL (or at least by  my outdated programming knowledge). Some of the other .csv or .xlsx files don't have all the frequencies I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are subscription based services by companies like Jeppesen and Lufthansa that provide such data, at a price.

Free data is only available in more cumbersome formats like PDF documents and websites. Handy for looking up individual airports for your trip planning but not for automated data mining.